# How to retrieve the "real" target element of an event in GWT

Tags: gwt

quick question on GWT from a newbie. Considering the following code:

```
FlowPanel block = buildMyBlock(); // buildMyBlock builds a FlowPanel with different widgets in it
block.addDomHandler(
    new ClickHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            // do some stuff
        }
    },
    ClickEvent.getType());
```

in the onClick() method, I'd like to be able to make different treatments depending on the internal elements that have been clicked inside block
Is it possible? And how ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget())` to retrieve the actual target of the event.

Comment: Also you can use getCurrentEventTarget if the element contains child elements. This will give you the element that last fired the event. This can be useful if the for example a button contains an icon and you want to get the button and not the icon that was originally clicked.